# $('#elemdiv') returns null but document.getElementById('elemdiv')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

`$('#elemdiv')` returns `null` but `document.getElementById('elemdiv')`. Recently jquery has started throwing errors. Such as with the line

```
$('#PlaceHolder')[0].innerHTML = ' ...';
```

but not with

```
document.getElementById('PlaceHolder')[0].innerHTML = ' ...
```

This is the first jquery that is run so fixing this one line will not fix the rest of the jquery.

jquery linked in line:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

also tried

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

error message: 
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

tried in IE 11 ,chrome and firefox

Comment: `$('...')` should never return null or undefined. Can you create a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: jQuery will need `.html();` and not `.innerHTML`

Comment: Saying `document.getElementById('PlaceHolder')[0].innerHTML` doesn't make sense because `getElementById()` will never return an array or list: it either returns a single element or `null`. The error you quoted about "unable to get property '0' of undefined or null" could happen for that line.

Comment: @Ani `$('...')[0]` returns the element, which has a `.innerHTML` property. Why he's doing that instead of using `.html()`, I don't know.

Comment: Is your script called after jQuery is loaded? What does `console.log($, jQuery)` give you?

Comment: @JasonP Question - Is `.innerHTML` a valid property for jQuery?

Comment: @Ani No, but it is for javascript, and `$('...')[0]` doesn't return a jQuery object.

Comment: $('#PlaceHolder') where PlaceHolder is a div has a Value and Type of null. $('#PlaceHolder')[0].innerHTML =" ... " had been working.

Comment: document.getElementById('PlaceHolder') is showing a type of DispHTMLDivElement

Comment: and looking at the scripts in the debugger is showing jquery-1.9.1.js is loaded.

Comment: console.log($, jQuery) gives me undefined - so JQuery is not loaded. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to move the jquery-1.9.1.js reference to after this old project's script references. not sure why.

Thanks for all your help and comments.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you are dealing with a malformed html document. To isolate the issue, assuming it's being rendered server side somehow, I'd recommend saving the rendered version and removing portions of HTML code surrounding the particular control that's behaving strangely until jQuery can find it. Keep doing this until you can find the particular HTML that's causing the behavior.